# Removing NULLS from conditional aggregation results

Tags: sql, pivot, isnull

I'm having difficulty in removing NULLS. The ISNULL statement seems to work for the dynamic result, but not the second one.

My final extract query is :

```
select itemid,title,description,cat,fibre,washing,colours,promo,
   max(case when seqnum = 1 then isnull(chm_sizegrouping,'') end) as sizes_1,
   max(case when seqnum = 2 then isnull(chm_sizegrouping,'') end) as sizes_2,
   max(case when seqnum = 3 then chm_sizegrouping end) as sizes_3,
   max(case when seqnum = 4 then chm_sizegrouping end) as sizes_4)
```

Results shown are:

```
itemid  sizes_1 sizes_2
LM008   one     NULL
LM009           NULL
LM010           NULL
lm011           NULL
```

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select itemid,title,description,cat,fibre,washing,colours,promo,
       isnull(max(case when seqnum = 1 then chm_sizegrouping end),'') as sizes_1,
       isnull(max(case when seqnum = 2 then chm_sizegrouping end),'') as sizes_2,
........
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you have to use the `ISNULL` function to each field that could retrieve a `NULL` value.

Comment: Thats the odd thing, I have. The first column "sizes_1" contatins no NULLs however "sizes_2" does. Even though I have the ISNULL statement wrapped around the "sizes_2" extract.

Comment: You need to enclose max() into isnull() - `isnull(max(...), '')`, not vice versa.

Comment: Encapsulate max() inside the isnull function

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `ISNULL` checks on the outside of the `MAX()` functions, like this:

```
select itemid,title,description,cat,fibre,washing,colours,promo,
    isnull(max(case when seqnum = 1 then chm_sizegrouping end), '') as sizes_1,
    isnull(max(case when seqnum = 2 then chm_sizegrouping end),'') as sizes_2,
    max(case when seqnum = 3 then chm_sizegrouping end) as sizes_3,
    max(case when seqnum = 4 then chm_sizegrouping end) as sizes_4)
```